# Questions about struct initialization syntax intricacies

Tags: c++, syntax, initialization

I have gradually accumulated some open questions about the language's initialization syntax. Searching for answers can sometimes be relatively difficult when one does not know what to search for or is not aware of the correct terminology.

Are my assumptions as expressed in the comments below correct, and what is actually happening if not? I am using C++11.

```
struct Foo{};
Foo;       //1:  Error, this fails for all types, built-in or otherwise
Foo();     //2:  rvalue created by an explicit call to the default ctor "Foo::foo()"
Foo{};     //3:  rvalue created by specifying an empty initializer list,
           //    ..at which point is the default constructor called? How
           //    ..does this actually differ from #2?
Foo={};    //4:  Error, why does this syntax not work?
Foo(){};   //5:  Error, this one is quite obvious considering #2
Foo()={};  //6:  what exactly happens here?
Foo f;     //7:  instance created by implicit call to default constructor
Foo f{};   //8:  instance created by initializer list, similar to #3
Foo f={};  //9:  similar to #8
Foo f();   //10: function declaration.
Foo f()={};//11: Error, this is a malformed function declaration
Foo f(){}  //12: function definition
```

Comment: 3. is not an empty initializer list. It is *value initialization*, same as `Foo()` (except it is cannot be parsed as a function.) Same applies to 8.

Comment: So 2, 3 and 8 are value initializations and 9 is an aggregate initialization. I was not aware of the term "value initialization", and searching for it on the net yielded a comprehensive explanation.

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect 4 to do. Foo is not an object, so you can't assign to it; it's a structure definition

Comment: Yes, I do realize that now that I know about different _kinds_ of initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialization is a confusing topic because the various forms of initialization (direct-initialization, list-initialization, value-initialization, *etc.*) are not all mutually exclusive.

**I went through the C++11 standard and read all the gory details**, if you're curious. Here's a line-by-line analysis.

```
struct Foo{};
```

Since `Foo` is a class type, *default-initialization* of `Foo` calls the default constructor (8.5 [dcl.init] paragraph 6).

Since `Foo` is a non-union class type without a user-provided constructor, *value-initialization* of `Foo` entails *zero-initialization* followed by calling the implicitly-declared default constructor, if it is non-trivial. (8.5 [dcl.init] paragraph 7).

In this case, the implicitly-declared default constructor is trivial (12.1 [class.ctor], paragraph 5) and is equivalent to `Foo::Foo() {}` (*Id.*, paragraph 6).

`Foo` is an aggregate and may be initialized by an initializer list. (8.5.1 [dcl.init.aggr], paragraph 1)

```
Foo;
```

Ill-formed. However, the declaration `Foo Foo;` is valid and declares a variable named `Foo` of type `Foo`. The expression `Foo;` would then become valid. Needless to say, you shouldn't do this.

```
Foo();
```

This is an *explicit type conversion*. Since `Foo` is a non-array complete object type, this expression creates a prvalue of type `Foo`, which is value-initialized. (5.2.3 [expr.type.conv] paragraph 2).

```
Foo{};
```

This is also an explicit type conversion, which creates a prvalue of type `Foo` which is direct-list-initialized (*Id.*, paragraph 3). Since the *braced-init-list* is empty and `Foo` is a class type with a default constructor, the object is value-initialized (8.5.4 [dcl.init.list], paragraph 3).

```
Foo={};
```

Well, this doesn't make any sense. What did you expect it to do? (Note: Again, this becomes well-defined if `Foo` is a variable.)

```
Foo(){};
```

I agree, it's pretty obvious that this is ill-formed, at least as an expression. It is, however, valid syntax for the definition of the default constructor of `Foo`. (The extraneous semicolon is an empty declaration.)

```
Foo()={};
```

This creates the prvalue `Foo()` as previously detailed, then performs an assignment to it. This is allowed even though `Foo()` is an rvalue (13.5 [over.oper], paragraph 7). This expression on the whole is equivalent to `Foo().operator=({})` (5.17 [expr.ass], paragraph 9). It constructs a temporary `Foo` by aggregate-initialization from the *braced-init-list* `{}`, binds the temporary `Foo` to an rvalue reference, `Foo&&`, and calls `Foo`'s implicitly defined move assignment operator (12.8 [class.copy], paragraphs 20-21).

```
Foo f;
```

This invokes default initialization (8.5 [dcl.init], paragraph 11).

```
Foo f{};
```

This is list-initialization, since the initializer is a *braced-init-list* (8.5 [dcl.init], paragraph 16). Specifically it is *direct-list-initialization* (8.5.4 [dcl.init.list], paragraph 1). As in the case of `Foo{}`, value-initialization is performed.

```
Foo f={};
```

This is *copy-initialization* (8.5 [dcl.init], paragraph 14). Again, since the initializer is a *braced-init-list*, it is list-initialization; specifically, *copy-list-initialization* (8.5.4 [dcl.init.list], paragraph 1). Again, value-initialization is performed.

```
Foo f();
```

This is indeed a function declaration, since a statement which could be interpreted as either a function declaration or an object declaration is always interpreted as the former (8.2 [dcl.ambig.res], paragraph 1).

```
Foo f()={};
```

This can be interpreted as neither a valid object declaration nor a valid function declaration, so it is ill-formed.

```
Foo f(){}
```

Indeed, this is a function definition.

Answer (score 0):

After putting some thought into it, I arrived at the following conclusion:

- `Foo f;` is a *default initialization*.
- `Foo();`, `Foo{};` and `Foo f{};` are *value initializations*.
- `Foo f={};` is an *aggregate initialization*.
- `Foo()={};` and `Foo{}={};` are actually **multiple** operations: If I'm correct, a *value initialization* of `Foo()`, followed by a second *value initialization* of `{}` (the type is deduced by the compiler), and finally ending with an assignment operation (by the default assignment operator).
- `Foo f();` is treated as a function declaration
- `Foo f(){}` is a function definition